# NSURL response blocking special characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I have a NSURLConnection set up, but when the data it gets back is ÆØÅ fx. the response data becomes (null) ?

```
id String = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:connectionData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

That's the line saving the response

Comment: It'd be nice to see some code, please.

Comment: If you can't create a string with that method and utf8 encoding your data is most likely not encoded as utf8

Comment: If your allocating an `NSString` to `id String` why you not just use `NSString` seems pointless allocating to `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get back the NSData response, you need to convert it to an NSString using appropriate encoding (UTF8 should work for most of the cases). You may try ISO Latin1 encoding if UTF8 is not working.

Comment: Perhaps your response is not UTF8 encoded. You need to know the encoding used for the response. You may try ISO Latin1.